# What does "matches x and remembers the match" means in regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Pardon me if it seems to be trivial but just to understand regexps:
As said [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters) with character (x) :

```
(x)           matches x and remembers
```

First part "**matches**" I can understand but the second part "**remembers**" is a bit tedious for me to understand.
Can someone please help in explaining it in much easier way?

Comment: The variable `$1` will contain the value remembered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called capturing group. Using backreference (`$1`, `$2`, ...), you can reference it in the substitution string:

```
'R2D5'.replace(/(\d)/g, '$1$1')
// => "R22D55"
```

You can also use backreference (`\1`, `\2`, ...) in the pattern:

```
'ABBCCDEF'.match(/(.)\1/g)  // to match consecutive character
// => ["BB", "CC"]
```

And you will get additional parameters when you use replacement function:

```
'R2D5'.replace(/(\d)/g, function(fullMatch, capture1) {
    return (parseInt(capture1) + 1).toString();
})
// => "R3D6"
```

Comment: And when using a function with `replace`, capture groups are the second (and on) arguments: `'R2D5'.replace(/(\d)/g, function(fullMatch, capture1) { ... })`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Thank you for your comment. I updated the answer to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

In most regex stuff you can specify a "capturing group" and recall them later:

```
"something".replace(/so(me)/, '$1 ')
```

Here, the capturing group is `(me)` - the result will be `me thing`